# How to output a chart from Nielsen?

Tags: r, graph, charts, ggplot2

I saw an interesting chart on engadget today made by Nielsen:

http://www.engadget.com/2011/07/28/nielsen-android-leads-us-smartphone-market-with-39-percent-shar/

original source: http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/online_mobile/in-u-s-smartphone-market-android-is-top-operating-system-apple-is-top-manufacturer/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+NielsenWire+%28Nielsen+Wire%29

I'd love for someone to replicate it if possible and show the R code. Basic packages or ggplot2 would be great.

I like that the boxes are proportional, that's a key feature :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find several implementations in R under the name of 'mosaic chart'. E.g.:

```
require("vcd")
data(HairEyeColor)
mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE)
```

[image]

Se some examples on e.g. [quickR](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/mosaic.html), but searching the [R graph gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/search.php?q=mosaic&engine=RGG) is also a good option.

In ggplot2, you can find a sample on [learnr's blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/).

I have also done some tweaks in ggplot2, please find the attached plot below. It is in Hungarian, but if you are interested, I could clean up the code and post is somewhere.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: I have searched for my old script based on comment and uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g89Nd67a). Sorry, no code clean up and it is quite messy, as I had to make it up for mass reporting from SPSS data files, but I hope you could use it. The usage is simple: load all functions (e.g.: run all lines in R with the `source(...)` function), and you could generate a mosaic chart of any data frame by specifying two variable names in the parameters of `ggMosaicChart()`. The plot will be saved to a png file in the working directory (no easy resize in R of the plot as lots of manual tweaks are done to arrange text nicely).

I have translated the strings to English, a basic example (included in the above code) of the `mtcars` data set:

[image]

Count, row- and column percent and also Pearson residuals are shown for each cell.

Comment: Could you try to mimic the data in the provided link? I'll give you answer credit ;)

Comment: @datayoda: I have updated my answer, I hope you could use it. Sorry for no cleanup, but it has been a while I made up the script and quite under the water now. But will deal the problem later and post here my news :)

Answer (score 2):

It's called treemap. R project has packages named "treemap" or "portfolio" for it. Here is how to do: http://flowingdata.com/2010/02/11/an-easy-way-to-make-a-treemap/